# sending friend request to multiple facebook user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to send friend request to multiple facebook user from my web-app.

I know that sending request to sigle user can be done using this link:
http://www.facebook.com/addfriend.php?id=PROFILE_ID

Is there a way i can do that for multiple user???

Comment: Are you talking about sending multiple requests Using Facebook? or you Facebook APPLICATION? also where did you get the link above?

Comment: I am developing a rails app where a user will have a list of email ids. I am planning to allow the user to add those emails in his contact list(google/yahoo/hotmail/.. contacts) or send friend nvitation(facebook/linkedin/...)I have worked that out for google and yahoo..Currently I m working on facebook invitation.......Sending seperate request for each profile is not possible because it would prompt the user to click 'add friend' for every single request...So what I want is something similar to "facebook application request" where the user would be able to select users and send request to all

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an array of users.
Loop through those users and call the addfriend.php url.

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    file_get_contents('http://www.facebook.com/addfriend.php?id=' . $user->id);
}
```

Or something like that.

I'm using file_get_contents here, but you can use whatever you like ofcourse.